# Is it a good idea to do Cross-Validation for LASSO with a small sample size?

Tags: cross-validation, matlab, lasso

I have a dataset consist of 40 rows and 15 terms as variables. I need to develope a "prediction model" based on LASSO classification. Thus, I want know the best significant terms with their coefficients. Since my sample size is small (40) and I have 15 predictors, is it a good idea to do cross-validation on my dataset?

if so, what would be the best value for CV?

If not, how can I extract the best model from the Lambda matrix, B, (*B=lassoglm(X,Y)*) having the minimal deviance?

**FYI**: when I use Cross-Validation, I get different non-zero coefficients. e.g. in 50 runs some of the terms appeared 40 times as nonzero coefficients

Answer (score 3):

Yes, crossvalidation is the way to go. Use 40 folds (leave-one-out) when you have a small sample size.

That you get different non-zero coefficients is fairly normal. LASSO should not be seen as a tool to reliably identify which coefficients "should" be in the model: there will typically be a correlated pair of covariates, and then it doesn't matter so much which of the two goes into the model, and the choice is random.

LASSO is primarily a tool for making a pragmatic prediction model that is "economic" in the sense that you can use it while collecting only a subset of the covariates that were used in the model fit.